# React. load different data arrays into slick slider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, slick.js

So at this stage I have a component in which I draw a slider, the photos of which are routes to certain rooms.  The task now is to bring the slider to a separate page(component) ... which will open for the pages: rooms / news / promotions passing different arrays . Is it possible to do this in a reactor or is it a bad case and this task needs to be solved differently, I don’t even understand how to do it

```
  <Slider ref={slider => (this.slider = slider)} {...settings}>
      {RoomsService.rooms.map(room => {
        return (
          <div className="rooms_slider">
            {room.title === 'Soon' ? (
              <img src={room.img} />
            ) : (
              <Link to={`/rooms/${room.id}`}>
                <img src={room.img} />
              </Link>
            )}

          </div>
        );
      })}

    </Slider>
```

Comment: Where in memory you store the condition of `rooms, new, promotions`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what your question is, but you should be able to take everything you have done with the slider and abstract it out to a component that you simply pass props into.

```
const CustomSlider = ({rooms, settings}) => {
  return (

    <Slider ref={slider => (this.slider = slider)} {...settings}>
      {rooms.map(room => {
        return (
          <div className="rooms_slider">
            {room.title === 'Soon' ? (
              <img src={room.img} />
            ) : (
              <Link to={`/rooms/${room.id}`}>
                <img src={room.img} />
              </Link>
            )}

          </div>
        );
      })}

    </Slider>
  )
};
```

```
<CustomSlider rooms={[{title,  img, id}]} settings={someSettingObj} />
```

From here you can conditionally render things based on the props available.